# Laravel Validator multiple unique rules for different tables

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using `unique` rules for multiple `email` parameters in the `Request $request` with their respective tables.

```php
...
'company_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
'personal_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:companies',
...
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

The column that's storing email for both tables is name `email`.
When I send value for `personal_email` I encounter following error.

```php
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;personal_email&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039; (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `personal_email` = email@email.com)
```

My Question is that how can I specify the actual column name for both rules?

**Environment:**

Laravel 5.8

Comment: `unique:table,column`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Use like this : 

`'company_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,users_table_email_column_name',
'personal_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:companies,companies_table_email_column_name',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it after `unique:users` and `unique:companies` rules

```
'company_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,users_email_column',
'personal_email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:companies,companies_email_column',
```